# C# PowerPoint without Open Office SDK and Microsoft Office Interop

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have a big problem - i must create application which will be create PowerPoint file with images from folder in the  slides. It will be part of project which use Framework 2.0(OpenOfficeXML SDK 2.0 require 3.5). And we cannot use  Microsoft Office Interop. How i may solve this problem?

Comment: There is an [OpenXML API for .Net 2 on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openxmlapinet2/), it looks a bit sketchy though so I would give it a virus scan before you do anything with it.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can purchase a 3rd party library. These guys claim to support all the way back to .NET 1.1:  http://www.aspose.com/.net/powerpoint-component

2) You can spend a ton of hours reading up on the raw file format and create the file by manually writing out the appropriate XML and zipping it up.